# Pseudo equation inside verse: how to align left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, verse

I am trying to typeset a song where some lines are repeated. In order to tell what are they, I grouped them using right curly brackets.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
la la\\
\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
  \text{blah blah}\\
  \text{ha ha ha}\\
\end{rcases}
\text{repeat 2 times}
\end{equation*}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Unfortunately the text inside equation is being centered. How can I align it left?

This is not an equation, but I don't know, how to implement such a non-standard requirement and mark the repeated lines without using equation trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a displayed-equation environment. Use inline math mode instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
la la\\
$
\begin{rcases}
  \text{blah blah}\\
  \text{ha ha ha}\\
\end{rcases}
\text{repeat 2 times}
$
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @Bernard has pointed out in a comment, the `rcases` environment is defined by the `mathtools` package. Instead of using lower-level math commands inside the `verse` environment, it's probably better to create a dedicated macro -- called `\vrepeat` below; it takes two arguments -- that lets you achieve the desired formatting.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verse,amsmath,mleftright}
\newcommand\vrepeat[2]{%
  \smallskip$\mkern-1.7mu\mleft.\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  #1\end{tabular}\mright\}$#2}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
la la\\
\vrepeat{blah blah\\
         ha ha}{
         repeat 2 times}\\
la la la
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good idea, but two tiny problems ... (1) braced lines are flushed right to brace; precede by `&` to left-align them with one another; (2) they are indented by a small distance; reverse this by `\mspace{-\medmuskip}` before each line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Good suggestions indeed! :-) The OP didn't mention these "two tiny problems", so I didn't point them out in my answer...

Comment: @Mico: `rcases` already exists in `mathtools`…

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks. I've provided an addendum to (a) point out that `mathtools` provides an environment called `rcases` and (b) provide a dedicated macro that lets the user enter the repeat-related information without having to resort to explicit math mode commands inside a `verse` environment.

Comment: @Mico: Nice. I wondered whether ‘Repeat 2 times’ meant ‘Sing twice’ or ‘Sing thrice’?

Comment: @Bernard It meant "Sing twice"

Comment: The ‘Repeat’ or ‘Twice’ mean  exactly that  but not both.

Comment: @Bernard Good point, I'll change it to "Repeat" in my original text to avoid misreading.

Answer (score 5):

No math required: you canuse  the `blkarray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
La la la\\
La la la\\[1ex]
\begin{blockarray}{@{}l\Right{\}}{\footnotesize\enspace Repeat twice}}
 blah blah\\
 ha ha ha
\end{blockarray}\\[ -2ex]
La la la \end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to move the repeated part *outside* of the verse environment, here is another approach, with some parameters you can fine-tune.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

\setlength{\mathindent}{26pt} % <--- fine tune

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
la la\\
\end{verse}
\vspace{-1.4\baselineskip} % <--- fine tune
\begin{align*}
\begin{rcases}
  \text{blah blah}\\
  \text{ha ha ha}\\
\end{rcases}&\text{\ repeat 2 times}&
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```